# How to apply middleware for Permission in Route Dynamically in Laravel (Spatie Permission)?

Tags: php, laravel-8

In my Laravel application, I have 5 pages. This is just an example.

- About
- Service
- TermsAndCondition
- PrivacyPolicy
- Contact

For display those page i have create one controller called PageController.

PageController

```
public function index($page)
{
    return view('page', compact('page));
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/{page}', [PageController::class, 'index'])->where('page' => ['about|service|termscondition|privacypolicy|contact']);
```

For manage permission, I am using Spatie Permission package.

I have some permission. e.g

- about.view
- service.view
- termscondition.view
- privacypolicy.view
- contact.view

User only can view those pages after login if they have permission (This concept is for demo purpose only).

If I have individual route for every page then I can apply `middleware('can:about.view')` like this way.

But in this case, where i am using one route for every pages dynamically, so how can I apply middleware for permission?

Comment: You need an entity Page and use policy for this entity. In controller, not in middleware like `$this->authorize('view', $page)`

Comment: Can I implement this policy along with Spatie Permission package?

Comment: Read here: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/best-practices/using-policies

Comment: Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

Make entity Page (if you don't have a model) like this:

```
class Page implements UrlRoutable
{
    private string $page;

    public function __construct(string $page)
    {
        $this->page = $page;
    }

    public function getPage(): string
    {
        return $this->page;
    }


    public function getRouteKey()
    {
        return $this->getPage();
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'page';
    }

    public function resolveRouteBinding($value)
    {
        return new self($value);
    }
}
```

***Hint:** Implementing `UrlRoutable` contract allow us to use this class in routing like model.*

Make a `PagePolicy` for Page like other policies

```
class PagePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function view(User $user, Page $page)
    {
        $permission = 'view.' . $page->getName();
        return $user->can($permission);
    }
    
    //other methods
}
```

Register policy in `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
    protected $policies = [
        Page::class => PagePolicy::class
    ];
```

And than, in controller, you can just use gate functional:

```
    public function index(Page $page)
    {
        $this->authorize('view', $page);
        //or
        Gate::check('view', $page);
        return view('page', compact('page'));
    }
```

Or use this in middleware:

```
Route::get('/{page}', [PageController::class, 'index'])->where('page' => ['about|service|termscondition|privacypolicy|contact'])->middleware('can:view');
```

Comment: In my case, I am using Page model. But this is a perfect solutions for me. Thank you so much @Maksim